# looping through multidimensional array from post and save to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array, foreach

This is the array which i get from post

```
Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [Invoice] => Array
                (
                    [itemNo] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => rtgrg
                            [1] => 4t4t
                            [2] => ththt
                            [3] => thth
                        )

                    [itemName] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => rtgrt
                            [1] => 4t5t5
                            [2] => hthtyh
                            [3] => gnghnn
                        )

                    [itemDiscription] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 5tr5t
                            [1] => t45t4
                            [2] => tyhthtyh
                            [3] => gnghnh
                        )

                    [price] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 2
                            [1] => 10
                            [2] => 9
                            [3] => 12
                        )

                    [itemQuantity] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 2
                            [1] => 12
                            [2] => 9
                            [3] => 9
                        )

                    [itemDiscount] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 11
                            [1] => 0.14
                            [2] => 0.13
                            [3] => 0.1
                        )

                    [itemTotal] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 333333
                            [1] => 34535
                            [2] => 55555555555555
                            [3] => 666666666
                        )

                    [itemStartDate] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                            [1] => 
                            [2] => 
                            [3] => 2016-06-17
                        )

                    [itemEndDate] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                            [1] => 
                            [2] => 
                            [3] => 
                        )

                    [itemCustomcol] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 4t4t4
                            [1] => t5trgr
                            [2] => htht
                            [3] => gngh
                        )

                    [itemCustomcol2] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => t4t4t
                            [1] => rtgtr
                            [2] => thth
                            [3] => gng
                        )

                    [itemttax2] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => tax1
                        )

                    [itemttax3] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => tax1
                        )

                    [itemttax4] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => tax1
                        )

                    [itemtCsTax] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => gngn
                        )

                    [itemtCsTaxPer] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 0.1
                        )

                    [itemtDiscount] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 0.18
                        )

                    [itemtInvReceived] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => gngn
                        )

                    [itemtInvToReturn] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => gngng
                        )

                    [itemInvDue] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => nghnghng
                        )

                    [itemInvComment] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => hngnhg
                        )

                )

        )
```

There is  a separate table for dynamic input like itemName, itemDiscription to itemCustomcol2 and another table for itemttax2 to itemInvComment .

I tried foreach loop for multiple element array but this doent work for me as it returns a string. one of them is shown below

```
    $capture_field_vals ="";
        foreach($_POST["data"]["Invoice"]["itemNo"] as $key => $text_field){
            $capture_field_vals .= $text_field .", ";
        }
echo $capture_field_vals;
```

What i want is collect all element[0] and then insert it in a row mysql and then another element another row and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you can't use the following format?

```
Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [Invoice] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [itemNo] => number
                            [itemName] => name
                            [itemDescription] => desc
                            [price] => 0.00
                        ),
                    [1] => Array
                            (
                                [itemNo] => number
                                [itemName] => name
                                [itemDescription] => desc
                                [price] => 0.00
                            ),...
```

with this method you can loop through retrieving all details of each item in the invoice?

If I have misunderstood your problem, I apologise

Comment: Thnx for quick reply and pointing to this direction.I use a for loop for multiple element then I collect it dynamic variable and then if no error then in another loop i use insert statement. Is this correct way to do this.I read do use dynamic variables.